# Adding TwinPrime to my HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, androidhttpclient

TwinPrime is an SDK that supposedly enhances your app's internet connectivity by 100% with a few lines of code (www.twinprime.com).

Apparently all I need to do is place the following code in my MainActivity:

```
new TwinPrimeSDK(getApplicationContext(), "API_KEY");
try {
    URLConnection httpConn = TPURLConnection.openConnection("your-URL");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then attach the following wherever there is an HttpConnection:

```
URLConnection httpConn = TPURLConnection.openConnection("your-URL");
```

My problem is I have no idea where to attach it. I've contacted their customer support but maybe somebody on SO has had experience with them?

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null) {
            return b;
        }

        // Download Images from the Internet
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            FeedUtils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `enhances your app's internet connectivity by 100%` Well what would that mean?

Comment: Heck if I know! Sounds interesting though.

Comment: To be honest i would review whether you need some sort of service like this and review their privacy policy, looks like they provide this by analysis  data about your connections. http://www.twinprime.com/privacy-policy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I accomplished it.

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null) {
            return b;
        }

        // Download Images from the Internet
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) TPURLConnection.openConnection(url);
//            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
            httpConn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            httpConn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is = httpConn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            FeedUtils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            httpConn.disconnect();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        }
    }
```